# How does DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI's connect_info work?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

The [docs for connect_info](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI#connect_info):

> **connect_info**
>
> This **method** is normally called by "connection" in DBIx::Class::Schema,
>   which encapsulates its argument list in an arrayref before passing
>   them here.
>
> The argument list may contain:
>
> - The same 4-element argument set one would normally pass to "connect"
>     in DBI, optionally followed by extra attributes recognized by
>     DBIx::Class:
>
>   ```
>   $connect_info_args = [ $dsn, $user, $password, \%dbi_attributes?, \%extra_attributes? ];
>   ```
> - A single code reference which returns a
>     connected DBI database handle optionally followed by extra attributes
>     recognized by DBIx::Class:
>
>   ```
>   $connect_info_args = [ sub { DBI->connect (...) }, \%extra_attributes? ];
>   ```
> - A single hashref with all the attributes and the dsn/user/password
>     mixed together:
>
>   ```
>   $connect_info_args = [{
>       dsn => $dsn,
>       user => $user,
>       password => $pass,
>       %dbi_attributes,
>       %extra_attributes,
>   }];
>
>   $connect_info_args = [{
>       dbh_maker => sub { DBI->connect (...) },  
>       %dbi_attributes,
>       %extra_attributes,
>   }];
>   ```
>
>   This is particularly useful
>     for Catalyst based applications, allowing the following config
>     (Config::General style):
>
>   ```
>   <Model::DB>
>       schema_class   App::DB
>       <connect_info>
>           dsn          dbi:mysql:database=test
>           user         testuser
>           password     TestPass
>           AutoCommit   1
>       </connect_info>
>   </Model::DB>
>   ```
>
>   The `dsn`/`user`/`password` combination can be substituted by the `dbh_maker` key
>     whose value is a coderef that returns a connected DBI database handle
>
> Please note that the DBI docs recommend that you always explicitly set
>   `AutoCommit` to either 0 or 1. DBIx::Class further recommends that it be
>   set to 1, and that you perform transactions via our "txn_do" in
>   DBIx::Class::Schema method. DBIx::Class will set it to 1 if you do not
>   do explicitly set it to zero. This is the default for most DBDs. See
>   "DBIx::Class and AutoCommit" for details.

What is this? Is it a method called internally, or a global? And, if it's a method called internally why is it being sent either a dbh maker, or four arguments? What determines what it is sent? It's listed as being a method. What is `$connect_info_args`?

Comment: If you're going to dump an entire section of documentation, can you please at least format it so it's readable? Just the link would have been better than that indecipherable mess.

Comment: It's relevant if you inherit from a schema class and want to influence how a connection is being made. That could be for debugging purposses, or to inject a test database, or something similar. It's also interesting because it returns the connection information, which again is useful for testing, debugging, profiling and probably also in strange production cases. I will not post this as an answer because I am too tired to elaborate. If you just use DBIC you don't need to deal with this.

Comment: Sure, is this a method an argument? Is $connect_info_args what I'm getting, or what I'm returning? What does the method get? does it have two signatures?

Comment: You could say it has two signatures, yes. But Perl doesn't have that concept. All Moose accessors are getter and setter a the same time, but the setter can take at least two different parameter sets and will know what to do in this case. Please specify what you are trying to do, or if you were just reading the docs and got confused and wanted to someone to explain this.

Comment: `connect_info` doesn't work. That's why there is no example of it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got it to work

## Schema Class

You've got to use the storage that's done like this (and you can find it in the docs)

```
package MyDBIC::Schema;
__PACKAGE__->storage_type("DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI::mysql::MySubClass")
```

## Storage Class

```
package DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI::mysql::MySubClass;
use mro 'c3';
use base 'DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI::mysql';
sub connect_info {
     my $self = shift;
     my $retval = $self->next::method([{
         username => _username(),
         password => $password,
         dsn => "my:dsn:"
     })
     $retval;
};
```

I found a rough example of how to do it [burred here](https://github.com/dbsrgits/dbix-class/blob/90a5b0237843707bba83646e8d14f6bf4b782ba5/lib/DBIx/Class/Storage/DBI/NoBindVars.pm#L34). Talk about shitty docs..

## <s>`connect_info` appears to be broke. Things tried.</s>

- Subclassing a Storage with a custom `connect_info`. It gets called, but nothing it returns does anything useful. Calling `->connect->storage->ensure_connected;` on a schema results in error.
- Wrapping `connect_info` with Moose::around(). Fails to wrap. `The method 'connect_info' was not found in the inheritance hierarchy`.
- Calling `$self->connect_info()` from `BUILD`... `DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI::connect_info` gets called but no matter what I hand to it, the sub only gets $self, the first argument.
- Calling `__PACKAGE__->connect_info({})` or `__PACKAGE__->connect_info([{}])` results in both arguments being sent to the `DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI::connect_info` but the lack of a `$self` results in `Class::XSAccessor: invalid instance method invocant: no hash ref supplied at` when the sub tries to write to the accessor.

Comment: The second error says 'contact_info' whereas it should be 'connect_info'.